# Is it possible to switch from the development version to the LTS version?

Tags: upgrade

I'm currently using the development version 22.04. If the LTS version of 22.04 is released at the end of April, can I switch to this LTS version instead of the development version?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Note: *beta-freeze* was reached on 28-March, and *beta* actually released (31-March-2022)

Comment: If you perform normal upgrades (ie. `apt full-upgrade`) regularly your system will become a full system when RC is reached.. ie. the *development* & codename will be replaced by 22.04, and you'll have a fully *functional* 22.04 system (*though disk comparisons may show differences due to dropped files etc that may exist on alpha or beta installs.. these file differences will not impact functionality though; they're just evidence of alpha/beta changes*)

Comment: 22.04 is currently slated to be the next LTS.  If you continue to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` throughout development and then also once it's released you will get 22.04 LTS.